# Handling Delegates on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm having a problem with the QueryString in my application.I have two buttons in my mainpage, when the user clicks on a button, the application navigates to the second page and stores the button ID on the Querystring.

Now, the problem I'm having is that if a user clicks on a button the Querystring "ID" key is set to the corresponding ID value BUT that value of ID then becomes persistant.

ie

Click Button1 => NavigationService("/Page2.xaml?ID=1",UriKind.Relative) => Check incoming ID value in onNavigated event of page2 and youu find that Querystring successfully set to ID in the second page.

but if you click the back button then press button2

Click Button2 => NavigationService("/Page2.xaml?ID=2",UriKind.Relative) => Check QueryString value in onNavidated event on page2 and you find that the ID key still as a value of 1.

If I had started off by pressing button2 then the ID key would have a persisted value of 2.

I have absolutely NO idea what could be going on.I have animated page transition between pages but I don't know how that could affect things.Does anyone have any ideas of what could be happening? Is there a way of reseting the whole app if I navigate back to the mainpage?

In MainPage

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            animation1.Stop();
            animation2.Stop();
            animation1.Begin();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {          
            animation2.Begin();
            animation2.Completed += (x, y) => NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/fooApp;component/Page2.xaml?id=1", UriKind.Relative));                           
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            animation2.Begin();
            animation2.Completed += (x, y) => NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/fooApp;component/Page2.xaml?id=2", UriKind.Relative));          
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            animation2.Begin();
            animation2.Completed += (x, y) =>   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/fooApp;component/Page2.xaml?id=3", UriKind.Relative));      
        }
```

In Page2

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e )
    {

       base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

       animation1.Stop();
       animation2.Stop();
       animation1.Begin();

    }
```

By the way I have commented out the entire Page2 Page Loaded event.

**UPDATE**

One thing I have noticed is that the program doesn't even run the second Navigation call, it only runs the first, I know this because if I change the Uri source in button2 to an empty string and run the program with button1 being the button that is pressed first, I will get the  querystring value stuck at 1 no matter which button I go back and press.When I look into the NavigationEventArgs e object in the OnNavigatedTo event in page2, it's URI source will always be the first uri source.

My guess right now is that the animation2.Completed event is acting as some sort of multicast delegate of sorts, Whatever gets put first into it is whatever will get run.Also, I removed the animations and just had the Navigation statement, the program worked fine but without the animation.Does anyone know how I can clear the animation2.Completed event? Or have any ideas on an alternate implementation.

Comment: It shouldn't happen, so there must be something wrong in your code. And if you don't show it to us, we'll have no way to tell what is wrong.

Comment: What about code for the receiving end (Page2.xaml)?  Also, from what I see here, it doesn't look like you are using any type of MVVM framework - is that correct?

Comment: I don't know what MVVM is so I don't think I'm using it.Is it possible that code I have written in other event handlers in page2 is causing the problem? I thought the onNavigated event was the first code to be run so how is that possible.

Comment: I currently have a breakpoint set at the beginning of the onNavigated event of page2 and I have added NavigationContext.QueryString["id"] to my watchlist, when I press one button it's ID reaches page2 but when I go back and press another one the ID that reaches page2 is the same ID as before.

Comment: `My guess right now is that the animation2.Completed event is acting as some sort of multicast delegate of sorts` => An event **is** a multicast delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're adding a `Completed` handler to your storyboard. The `Completed` handler navigates to page 2. Then you go back, and press the second button. Since you went back to previous page, you're re-using the same page instance, and therefore the same `Storyboard` instance. **Now you're adding a second `Completed` handler to your `Storyboard`**. So when the animation finishes, the `Storyboard` has two `Completed` handlers, the first one gets executed first, thus navigating to Page2 with the first parameters.

Instead of adding a `Completed` handler every time, just do it once for all, and store the URL in a property:

In your XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Animation2" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
    <!-- whatever-->
</Storyboard>
```

Then in your C# code:

```
protected string Uri { get; set; }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    animation1.Stop();
    animation2.Stop();
    animation1.Begin();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{          
    this.Uri = "/fooApp;component/Page2.xaml?id=1";
    animation2.Begin();                       
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Uri = "/fooApp;component/Page2.xaml?id=2";
    animation2.Begin();          
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Uri = "/fooApp;component/Page2.xaml?id=3";
    animation2.Begin();              
}

private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(this.Uri, UriKind.Relative));      
}
```

**Bonus:**

*Removing an event handler*

If you want to remove an event handler, simply use the `-=` operator. But then you can't use a lambda, you have to use a 'classical' method:

```
// Good
this.animation2.Completed -= Storyboard_Completed;

// Wrong
this.animation2.Completed -= (sender, e) => NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("RandomText_JustWantCompletedEventToBeHit", UriKind.Relative));
```

*Alternative implementation*

If all your buttons do is to trigger the animation and redirect to Page2, then you can handle it in a more generic way thanks to the `Tag` property of the controls. The `Tag` property allows you to to store any object you want to identify the control.

XAML:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button 1" Tag="1" />
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button 2" Tag="2" />
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button 3" Tag="3" />
```

C#:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
     this.Url = "/fooApp;component/Page2.xaml?id=" + element.Tag.ToString();

     animation2.Begin();
}
```